# PHP convert Win-1251 to UTF-8

Tags: php

I'm fetching the contents of a Windows-1251 encoded web site using file_get_html and want to serve it as UTF-8.

I set the headers to UTF-8 using: `header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');`

Then i output the data using `iconv("cp1252","UTF-8",'"desc":"'.$desc);`

The output is no longer strange questions marks, but it's still not Cyrillic.

Comment: Subject says Win-1251 and code cp1252. These are not the same are they? What does `iconv("cp1251",...` give you?

Answer (score 3):

Try not prepending anything to your string, letting it be just

```
iconv("cp1252","UTF-8",$desc);
```

By the way, do you get the cyrillic output if you just do

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=cp1252');
echo $desc; // No iconv
```

Comment: Yes I do, however my web application is UTF-8 so i have to use UTF8.

Comment: @user117701 ok, I have just read your answer. It seems you just misspelled your charset

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it, turns out it wasn't cp1252, but cp1251!